# 2 x drop down list with one common option. If selected from list 1, automatically selected in list 2

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, data-validation

I have 2 drop down lists with one item in common. If this item is selected in the first list I want it to be automatically selected in the second list. However, if it's not selected in the first list then the second drop down list should work as normal. The data for the lists are contained on a separate sheet in the same document and are dynamic using the OFFSET and COUNTA functions.

For example:
List one is Fruits, list two is vegetables and tomato appears in both lists.

If the user selects Tomato from list one then the cell with dropdown list two should automatically show Tomato.

If the user does not select Tomato from list one then the cell with dropdown list two should work as normal.

I can get this to work with a simple IF formula in the cell containing dropdown list two but after anything is selected from the dropdown list the IF formula is erased and the document no longer works.

Any guidance greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your rule to enable only "tomato", when "tomato" is selected in the other cell:

`=IF(E2="tomato",A2,OFFSET($A$2,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1))`

[image]

The only drawback of this method is that if both cells contains "tomato", then you'll need to delete it from both cells before you can enter another value.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've even managed to get round the drawback by using name ranges. However, this solution only limits the options in the second list to Tomato, it still needs to be selected. Is there a way that the cell containing the second list is automatically populated with Tomato if it selected from the first list? Or have I somehow implemented it incorrectly?

Comment: *edit.....I've not managed to get completely around the drawback but in my case it's not much of an issue.

Comment: You need to use macros for that.